# Приставка в слове «недорабатывать»

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор, приставка

Вопрос: какая приставка в слове "недорабатывают"?
Приставка **недо-** или две приставки (а именно: **не-** и **до-**)? Где бы я ни искал, нигде не упоминается о двух приставках. Но тогда возникает вопрос: какой способ словообразования будет в случае, если приставка *недо-*, и от какого слова оно будет образовано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что в слове "недорабатывают" две приставки.
Рассмотрим:
дорабо́тать (*сов.*; **до-**, -работ-, -а, -ть) — [дораба́тывать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) (*несов.*; **до-**, -рабат-, -ыва, -ть);
[недорабо́тать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) (*сов.*; **не-до-**, -работ-, -а, -ть) — недораба́тывать (*несов.*; **не-до-**, -рабат-, -ыва, -ть).

[недоработать | не/до/работ/а/ть](http://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/tih-n.htm) (Морфемно-орфографический словарь Тихонова)

Comment: Приставка меняет слова. Какое слово приставка до- изменила? Рабатывать?

Comment: Не филолог я, но знаю, что такой глагол есть. Из Нацкорпуса: Они век не рабатывали, птичек постреливали, ― сам знашь, сколько у них силы накопилось. [Федор Абрамов. Деревянные кони (1969)] Гляди-ко ― в версту вымахал каждый, а на барина единого дня не рабатывал! [П. П. Бажов. Змеиный след (1939)] Так, скажу тебе, Марья, работали, как я больше и сама не рабатывала и не видела, чтоб работали. [Валентин Распутин. Тетка Улита (1984)]

Comment: @shampar А еще есть устаревший глагол "работывать". Степан случайно познакомился с ним, когда еще в прежние годы тут работывал, свел даже какую-то хмельную дружбу и не раз в прежние годы вместе с ним бывал пьян. [В. И. Даль. Хмель, сон и явь (1843)]

Comment: Это аргумент, который достоин быть в тексте.